# Infeasibility of Pyomo Solution

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

I am working on a optimization problem in Pyomo and got a solution which does not meet all the constraints.

As a result, I used the log_infeasible_constraints model in Pyomo but it seems that it's not giving me the violated constraints.

To be specific, consider the following mad simple model with only two constraints and one objective function:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
from pyomo.util.infeasible import log_infeasible_constraints


model = AbstractModel()
model.N = Param( within=PositiveIntegers )
model.I= RangeSet( model.N )
model.x = Var(model.I,within=NonNegativeReals)

def lower_x(m):
    return sum(m.x[i] for i in m.I) >= 3

def upper_x(m):
    return sum(m.x[i] for i in m.I) <= 6

def obj(m):
    return sum(m.x[i]**2 for i in m.I)


model.value = Objective(rule=obj, sense=minimize)

model.c_lower = Constraint(rule=lower_x)
model.c_upper = Constraint(rule=upper_x)


data = {    None:{
    'N':    {None:  3}
}}


real_model = model.create_instance(data)


log_infeasible_constraints(real_model)
```

Obviously, no constraints are violated at optimal solution. But the results from the last line is:

```
INFO: CONSTR c_upper: 2.9999999712526666 </= 6.0
```

which confuses me a lot. Shouldn't the log_infeasible_constraints(real_model) only return the violated constraints? Could anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not well versed on the logging of infeasible constraints...but where are you *solving* the model.  I doubt this is valid until a solve attempt has been made....